# Replace Win 8.1 on Pipo W4 tablet with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, tablet

Windows 8.1 on a tablet with 1 GB RAM and a total of 16 GB memory!  Windows OS and a recovery partition occupies about 13-14 GB. So the space remaining for apps, downloads etc. is very limited.

So my question is:
Is it possible to wipe the entire memory and install Ubuntu on this tablet? It has a Intel Atom Z3735G processor.

Regards

Miniisar